# Build postgres query using JSON

Tags: python, json, angular, postgresql, orm

I am researching some way to build a query from JSON, something like an ORM that accepts JSON and converts to PostgreSQL query without having a model created with it. I want to build this query visually from angular 4 application.

I want to build with angular something like this:

```
query = {
    object: 'customers',
    filds: ['fidl1', 'field2' ... ]
    where: [
       and: { 
          field: 'field1',
          conition: 'equal',
          comparator: 5
       }
    ],
    order: [
       {
          field: 'field1'
          order: 'ASC'
       }
     ]
}
```

And then convert this into:

```
SELECT field1, field2 ... FROM customers WERE field1 = 5 ORDER BY field1 ASC
```

Any ideas?.

By the way, I am using python as backend

Comment: What about [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)?

Comment: @michel.milezzi I think that sequelize is only for node.js, I forgot to mention that I need an ORM for python.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for GraphQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, GraphQL almost resolve my problem but I don't have models previously created, the json is generated in frontend dynamically.

Comment: Check out [restSQL](http://restsql.org/doc/Overview.html)  or [pgrest](https://github.com/pgrest/pgrest) or [postgrest](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest)